# Add new view mode and set it as default

Tags: local.xml, list-view

I have set a new view mode on my catalog toolbar and it's work.
But i would like to make it as default list view.
How can I do it?
I try with my local xml adding this:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setData"><data>_current_grid_mode</data><mode>list</mode></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setData"><data>_current_grid_mode</data><mode>list</mode></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

But nothing change!

Answer (score 0):

You can change default view from admin as well

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Frontend -> List mode
```

For custom view type using observer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78236/category-product-list-add-a-custom-view-mode-via-observer) will help you.

Comment: I can't because I would like to set my custom list 'b2b order list' mode as defualt, and I can't see it in this configuration menu